# how to get the size of csv file line by line?is thas possible using python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-excel, filesize

I am reading a csv file without pandas library,i need to find out the number of bytes  of each row.So i can ad all the bytes and determine the file size and will do some restriction based on that.

```
file="Emptycsv.csv"
checkfilesize(file)

def checkfilesize(file):
 file=b''join(file).split(b'\n')
 count=len(file)
```

Count will print the number of rows.i need to find out the file size,i know os.path.getsize will do..But while reading that csv file row by rows/column or columns if it reached 109997897kb,i need to terminate.So request you to help me the find the bytes of data

Comment: `os.path.getsize()` returns the size of the file in bytes. Why can't you use that?

Comment: yes, it will ...But i am reading this csv file and writing into another csv file by line by line so i get the bytes of data ,i will check another csv file should have only 79mb(size restriction i can do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should work for getting the bytes per row/line:
(The +1 is for the newline)

```py
import os

total_bytes = -1

with open("test.csv") as file_in:
    for line in file_in:
        bytes_on_this_line = len(line) + 1
        total_bytes += bytes_on_this_line
        
print(total_bytes)

print(os.path.getsize("test.csv"))
```

Output:

```
15
15
```

Comment: Exactly this is what am looking for..Thanks